# Convert Pandas GroupBy to DataFrame

Tags: pandas

I have the following dataframe `table_1`:

```
     Sample  method       value
3   sample1  method_0     1
3   sample1  method_1     2
3   sample1  method_2     3
3   sample1  method_3     4
3   sample2  method_0     5
3   sample2  method_1     6
3   sample2  method_2     7
3   sample2  method_3     8


grouped = table_1.groupby('method')
```

And I want to group by 'method', and then for each group, divide the entries in the 'value' column for that group by another Series that has the same number of entries as there are entries in each group. I've been accomplishing this by doing:

```
table_2 = grouped.apply(lambda x: x['value'].div(series_of_two_elements))
```

But now I want to merge `table_2` into each group in `table_1`. When I try:

```
table_1['normalized'] = table_2
```

I get:

```
TypeError: 'DataFrameGroupBy' object does not support item assignment
```

How can I convert `table_1` back into a DataFrame so that I can assign these new normalized values for each group? Can I use a lambda expression with `df.transform`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think need [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) and for `Series` add `.values` for numpy array for avoid alignment:

```
series_of_two_elements = pd.Series([1,2])

grouped = table_1.groupby('method')
table_2 = grouped['value'].transform(lambda x: x.div(series_of_two_elements.values))
table_1['normalized'] = table_2

print (table_1)
    Sample    method  value  normalized
3  sample1  method_0      1         1.0
3  sample1  method_1      2         2.0
3  sample1  method_2      3         3.0
3  sample1  method_3      4         4.0
3  sample2  method_0      5         2.5
3  sample2  method_1      6         3.0
3  sample2  method_2      7         3.5
3  sample2  method_3      8         4.0
```

Another possible solution is create `MultiIndex` with second level by [`cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) and then use [`div`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.div.html) by second level (`Series` called `series_of_two_elements` has to be with same index values like `second level` for each group):

```
series_of_two_elements = pd.Series([1,2])

table_1 = table_1.set_index(['method', table_1.groupby('method').cumcount()])
table_1['normalized'] = table_1['value'].div(series_of_two_elements, level=1)
print (table_1)
             Sample  value  normalized
method                                
method_0 0  sample1      1         1.0
method_1 0  sample1      2         2.0
method_2 0  sample1      3         3.0
method_3 0  sample1      4         4.0
method_0 1  sample2      5         2.5
method_1 1  sample2      6         3.0
method_2 1  sample2      7         3.5
method_3 1  sample2      8         4.0
```

Comment: Thank you! The key was using the column of the GroupBy object `grouped['value']`! Because not all of the columns were numeric